# mapping object throws error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a basic mapping function which  is just doing a basic fetch from the database. All I want to do is once fetched just display it all to the screen.

This is the error I recieve

```
×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/Henry Peters/Codestone%20Workstation%20Self-Assessment%20Portal%202/src/Components/PageDetails/CompletedAssessments/CompletedAssessments.js:211
  208 |       return (
  209 |         <div >
  210 |             
> 211 | <li> {this.state.selectedSet.RUId}</li>
      | ^  212 | <li> <b>{this.state.selectedSet.QuestionId}</b></li> 
  213 | 
  214 |         </div>
```

This is my class in question

```
class Questions extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(props);
    this.state = { ...props,  };
    this.checker = this.checker.bind(this)
}

checker( ){
    this.setState({viewDetails : true})
    let workStation = window.localStorage.getItem("Workstation")
    let date = this.state.questions.Date
    let email = window.localStorage.getItem("User")

    fetch(`/show-questions-answered/${date}/${workStation}/${email}`)
    .then(recordset => recordset.json())
    .then(results => {
      this.setState({ selectedSet: results.recordset });
      console.log(this.state.selectedSet)   
    });
  alert(`${date} this is the boolena ${this.state.viewDetails}`)
}

  render() {
     console.log(`${this.state.previousDate} PREVIOUS DATE ${this.state.questions.Date}  DATE`)  

      if (!this.state.viewDetails){
      return (
          <div  >
          <button onClick = {this.checker}className= "btn btn-primary" style = {{float : "right"}}>View Details</button>

          <br />

          <li>  {this.state.questions.Date }</li>

        </div>
      );}
      else{
        return(<div  >
          <button onClick = {this.checker}className= "btn btn-primary" style = {{float : "right"}}>View Details</button>

          <br />

          <li>  {this.state.questions.Date }</li>
          <h3>BUTTON ClIcKED</h3>


          {this.state.selectedSet &&
              this.state.selectedSet.map(function( index) { 
                return (
                  <div >

          <li> {this.state.selectedSet.RUId}</li>
          <li> <b>{this.state.selectedSet.QuestionId}</b></li> 

                  </div>
                );
              })} 

        </div>

        )
      }

}}
```

```
console.log(this.state.selectedSet)
```

does work and does supply information and contained database table names such as RUId, questionId etc

so this.state.selectedSet.QuestionId should work

Comment: Can you add the structure of `this.state.selectedSet`. Is it an array maybe?

Comment: its a json object returned from express

Comment: Can you add the object structure?

Comment: `0: {RUId: 18, QuestionId: 29, Date: "2020-02-12T00:00:00.000Z", QuestionWhenAnswered: "Is the keyboard separate from the screen?", QuestionResponse: "Accepted", …}
1: {RUId: 18, QuestionId: 30, Date: "2020-02-12T00:00:00.000Z", QuestionWhenAnswered: "Does the keyboard tilt?", QuestionResponse: "Accepted", …}
2: {RUId: 18, QuestionId: 31, Date: "2020-02-12T00:00:00.000Z", QuestionWhenAnswered: "Is it possible to find a comfortable typing postion?", QuestionResponse: "Accepted", …}`

Comment: that the object structure. That is from the console.log as mentioned in the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this code:

```
{this.state.selectedSet &&
    this.state.selectedSet.map(function(index) {
        return (
            <div>
               <li>{this.state.selectedSet.RUId}</li>
               <li><b>{this.state.selectedSet.QuestionId}</b></li>
            </div>
        );
    })
}
```

to this:

```
{this.state.selectedSet &&
    this.state.selectedSet.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <div>
               <li>{item.RUId}</li>
               <li><b>{item.QuestionId}</b></li>
            </div>
         );
    })
}
```

Comment: My Man! This solved it as soon as I can set this as answer I will !